# Can't SSH to Virtualbox Linux Mint guest OS

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint 17 on my Virtualbox, and I want to access files in it.

I installed openssh-client and openssh-server by the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Then I tried ssh localhost by "ssh 127.0.0.1" and it shows the following:

```
Welcome to Linux Mint 17 Qiana (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64)

Welcome to Linux Mint
 * Documentation:  http://www.linuxmint.com
Last login: Fri Jun 27 13:18:53 2014 from localhost
```

I considered it as ssh successful from localhost. Then I tried to ssh from outside the Virtualbox.

I modified the network setting of the Linux virtual machine as follows:

> The VM network card is appended to "NAT"
>
> Port transfer set as "Rule1","TCP","","9023","10.0.2.15","22"
>
> Note: The corresponding fields are "name", "protocol", "host IP", "host port", "client IP", "client port"

Then I tried to connect to the Mint OS from Windows by FileZilla:

> Host: my host IP address
>
> User Name: my user name
>
> Password: my password
>
> Port: 9023

and the console showed that:

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:9023..
Status: Connection established, waiting for Welcome message..
Error: Can't connect to server
```

Then I tried to use "putty" to connect, but the putty console didn't show anything.

It seems the Virtualbox port transfer mechanism didn't work (since I could ssh to localhost in my Mint machine so I don't think it's the problem of the ssh I installed.) The port transfer mechanism worked well with my Ubuntu machines. I don't know why it doesn't work for Linux Mint.

Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you in advance.

====================================================

Thank you so much guys! This problem was solved by updating my Virtualbox. Here are the two settings I ran successfully:

1) NAT

Append interface of my VM(10.0.2.15) to NAT, and set the port forwarding rule as following:

> Port transfer set as "Rule1", "TCP", "", "9025", "10.0.2.15", "22"

Then I can ssh my VM (10.0.2.15) from outside Virtualbox by

> open"putty" in Windows and set SSH connection with my PC's public IP and port 9025

2) NAT-Network

Create a NAT-Network:

> CIDR: 10.0.3.0/24
>
> Port transfer set as "Rule1", "TCP", "", "9023", "10.0.3.4", "22" and "Rule2", "TCP", "", "9024", "10.0.3.5", "22"

Then Append two virtual machines (guest OS) to NAT-Network (Their IPs are 10.0.3.4 and 10.0.3.5 respectively)

Now the two machines can ping each other successfully, and they can access each other by (taking 10.0.3.4 as an example)

> ssh username@10.0.3.5

I can also ssh my VM (10.0.3.5) from outside Virtualbox by

> open"putty" in Windows and set SSH connection with my PC's public IP and port 9024

Comment: are you able to ping to you'r virtual machine. And It should be asked in supberuser?.

Comment: No. I was not able to ping my VM when its interface was appended to NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chech if you did install `openssh-server` server .

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

then check you have proper port enabled

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if you go in it with different port number from outside or your router has a rule of forwarding it to another port

you may also need to uncomment in there if you want to be authorized by password.

`#PasswordAuthentication yes`

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure two network interfaces on the guest OS. One for guest to host communication and other for guest to internet.

Please refer to [this tutorial](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=42385) on virtualbox forums.

Comment: No problems. I usually do not use NAT mode when using virtualbox. I use bridged adapter which brings the guest and host on the same network, as both query my WLAN Router's DHCP server.